# Mariadb configurations for optimal performance

Tags: mysql, configuration, mariadb

We have a table in mariadb with large number of row like 3 million. This table is been indexed . We have job which inserts 3 million records to this table. Query on this table takes more than a minute. Observation is query is fast after sometime the data is been inserted (say after 30 minutes).
Our observation is table indexing is taking time and once the indexing is done queries are executed quickly.
Sample query is like

```
select count(distinct userd_id) from users;
```

Where user_id column is indexed. Below is the explain on the query

```
   +------+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                     | type  | possible_keys | key                     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                        |
+------+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users                     | index | NULL          | index_on_user_id | 13      | NULL | 3505169 | Using index; Using temporary |
+------+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
```

What are the best configuration we can do to reduce the query execution time. 
System has 8 cores and 32 GB RAM and device has 500GB storage.

Comment: please share your schema and query. Please also post an "EXPLAIN" of the query

Comment: COUNT will take time specially if you are using InnoDB since it does not save the metadata like MyISAM. also, why DISTINCT on user_id ... user_id is NOT your PK?

Comment: I have another column as PK. Also query like select name,card,user_id from users where id in(23445,432353); is also taking lot of time

Comment: which version of MySQL you have? IN was optimized in 5.7 and it's faster than 5.5 or 5.6

Comment: I am using mariadb 10.3.10-MariaDB

Comment: Can you also provide a table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`

Comment: "What are the best configuration we can do to reduce the query execution time. System has 8 cores and 32 GB RAM and device has 500GB storage." Then you can better ask the question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/ .. Also the CPU cores will not help that much in MySQL there isn't anny query parallelisation in the CPU cores/threads, but you can configure the `innodb_buffer_pool` so the database runs more like a in memory database..

Comment: You can't solve performance problems with configuration changes!  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, maybe we can change the schema or query to improve performance.